# I just want to load a particular div on some actions in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I just want to load a  particular div on some actions in angular js.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id = "div_1" class="table-responsive" ng-controller="usercontroller" ng-init="displayData() ">
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead align="center">
          <tr>
            <th>Service Request Number</th>
            <th>Name of service request</th>
            <th>Date of request</th>
            <th>Closure date</th>
            <th>Current state</th>
            <th>Current owner</th>
            <th>Link to share point folder</th>
            <th>Schedule variance</th>
            <th align="center">Details</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in service track by $index">
            <td><span ng-bind="x.id"></span></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="x.sales_force_id"></span></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="x.submission_date"></span></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="x.closure_deadline"></span></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="x.item_status"></span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
    $scope.displayData = function()
        {
        alert($scope.firstRole);
        alert("nishant singh");

        if(empIVal == 1 && $scope.firstRole == 'Initiator' ){
                alert("i am a initiator");
                $http.get("commonGet.jsp?sqlStr=select * from service_request.service_request_data where emp_id="+empHidVal+ " order by id desc")
                .then(function(response){
                                $scope.service = response.data;



        });
        }
```

Here I want to load the `div` again when the `displayFunction()` is called and response is been returned. Also, the response is JSON object. I am able to call the function using `ng-change` directive and also able to get the desired JSON object, but I don't know how to load the `div` again after the response.

Comment: can you provide a plunker of the same

Answer (score 0):

wrap your assignment to service variable in timeout so that angular is aware of the changes

```
$timeout(function(){
      $scope.service = response.data;
});
```

Thus your whole method becomes something like this.

```
$http.get("commonGet.jsp?sqlStr=select * from service_request.service_request_data where emp_id="+empHidVal+ " order by id desc")
     .then(function(response){
          $timeout(function(){
                $scope.service = response.data;
          });

    });
 }
```

Comment: No, actually based on some change in the page, it will need to trigger a refresh to particular div not based on timeout.

Comment: I thought you want to refresh div if data in your table got changed.

Note: $timeout does not mean that we are executing it on some timeout, $timeout has an ability to call $scope.$apply which will reflect the change in your  data and will make angular aware of the changes

Comment: can i write this in the way:

Comment: how to write this timeout function with $http service :$http.get("commonGet.jsp?sqlStr=select * from service_request.service_request_data where emp_id="+empHidVal+ " order by id desc")
                .then(function(response){
                                $scope.service = response.data;

Comment: i tried the timeout but still that required div is not getting reloaded.

Comment: I am stuck help me out with this